# Drupal 7: can't get ckEditor module configured for inline editing

Tags: wysiwyg

Drupal 7: I using ckEditor module for editing within the textarea fields and I noticed on the ckeditor website that you can do inline editing like:
http://ckeditor.com/demo#inline

I can get the ckEditor module to work for regular editing but I can't seem to get it configured for inline editing like the demo listed above.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need [Quick Edit](https://www.drupal.org/project/quickedit), which is the Drupal 7 backport of the Spark core initiative for Drupal 8.